# How to position/place stacked column chart data labels vertically in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, graph, charts, bar-chart, excel-2016

I have the following stacked column chart (bar graph) in Excel:
[image]

The problem is that the chart data labels (percentages right on the green bars) do not fit and overlap. Data labels positioned horizontally. I want to position them **vertically**, but I couldn't find a way to do it in settings.

---

**Question:** how to position/place chart data labels vertically in Excel so that they fit in bars?

---

Moderators! Can you delete the question entirely? I see that SO community want so much to close it. Next time I will not ask such questions here. I better try on more adequate communities like quora or reddit.

---

*Uploaded Excel file to DropBox:* [*4.14SO.xlsx*](https://www.dropbox.com/s/du6nyon7yr9z4m2/4.14SO.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: This question is off-topic for [SO] and I have voted to close it.

Comment: Then tons of other similar questions must be deleted and closed. But they are kept. Double standards in action.

Comment: Explain how this is a programming related question.

Comment: Here on stackoverflow enormous number of questions that are not quite about programming. But the questions are not closed. But for some magical reason some questions are heavily donwvoted and closed while other similar questions are kept and open. May be someone better explain why such double standards in SO and why for some questions rules are followed while for others these rules ignored.

Comment: So you basic defense here to agree that this is off-topic, but say there are lots of other off-topic questions, so therefore  you are the victim of a double standard? You are more that welcome to escalate your complaint to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: As for your now deleted complaint about close and  downvotes. Yesterday I downvoted and voted to close about 50 blatantly off-topic questions tagged with [excel][graph]. If you have asked other questions. If you have asked other questions about charts in excel which fall into this category, then yes I probably downvoted other questions of yours.

Comment: Why still not deleted the question. Delete it. Close it. Whatever you like to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps...

Right click Data Labels --> Format Data Labels --> On Format Data Label Window, choose Size & Properties tab --> Alignment --> In there you can change the text direction of data labels as per your requirement.

Comment: SO community discourage people from answering questions by donwvoting answers. It is the only place where I see such mean behaviour.

Comment: Cool down Chichi! Every forum has it's own rules and regulations and both the asker and the solution provider should follow them. I would suggest you to follow the guidelines for asking a question in this forum. That will help you and others as well. Have a good day! :)

Comment: But the problem is that for some questions rules completely ignored. While for others not.

Comment: No worries. Each day thousands of questions are opened in the forum and it's not possible to track each question for a single person to make sure the rules are not violated. So if others are not following the forum guidelines that's their problem and they will face the consequences later or sooner. The bottom line is to learn from mistakes and move ahead. :)